# python reading lines in file and joining them

Tags: python, join, readline

I have this code

```
with open ('ip.txt') as ip :
    ips = ip.readlines()
with open ('user.txt') as user :
    usrs = user.readlines()
with open ('pass.txt') as passwd :
    passwds = passwd.readlines()
with open ('prefix.txt') as pfx :
    pfxes = pfx.readlines()
with open ('time.txt') as timer :
    timeout = timer.readline()
with open ('phone.txt') as num :
    number = num.readline()
```

which open all those files and join them in this shape

```
result = ('Server:{0} # U:{1} # P:{2} # Pre:{3} # Tel:{4}\n{5}\n'.format(b,c,d,a,number,ctime))
print (result)
cmd = ("{0}{1}@{2}".format(a,number,b))
print (cmd)
```

I supposed it will print like this

```
Server:x.x.x.x # U:882 # P:882 # Pre:900 # Tel:456123456789
900456123456789@x.x.x.x
```

but the output was like this

```
Server:x.x.x.x
 # U:882 # P:882 # Pre:900
 # Tel:456123456789
900
456123456789@187.191.45.228
```

New output :-

```
Server:x.x.x.x # U:882 # P:882 # Pre:900 # Tel:['456123456789']
900['456123456789']@x.x.x.x
```

how i can solve this ?

Answer (score 1):

may be you should remove `newline` using `strip()`

Example

```
with open ('ip.txt') as ip :
    ips = ip.readline().strip()
```

`readline()` will read one line at a time, where `readlines()` will read entire files as a list of lines

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing from your limited example is that `b` has a newline embedded. That's because of `readlines()`. The python idiom to use here is: `ip.read().splitlines()` where `ip` is one of your file handles.

See more splitlines options at [python docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html)

Answer (score 0):

Apart from other great answers, for completeness sake here I am going to post an alternative answer using `string.translate`, which will cover in case of any `\n` or newline has been accidentally inserted into middle of your string, like `'123\n456\n78'`, which will cover the corner cases from using `rstrip` or `strip`.

> Server:x.x.x.x # U:882 # P:882 # Pre:900 # Tel:['456123456789']
>
> 900['456123456789']@x.x.x.x

You have this is because you're printing a list, to resolve this, you need to join the string in your list `number`

Altogether, solution will be something Like this:

```
import string

# prepare for string translation to get rid of new lines
tbl = string.maketrans("","")

result = ('Server:{0} # U:{1} # P:{2} # Pre:{3} # Tel:{4}\n{5}\n'.format(b,c,d,a,''.join(number),ctime))
# this will translate all new lines to ""
print (result.translate(tbl, "\n"))
cmd = ("{0}{1}@{2}".format(a,''.join(number),b))
print (cmd.translate(tbl, "\n"))
```